# Jenkins, Mercurial, Bitbucket and SSH not working

Tags: mercurial, ssh, hudson, jenkins, bitbucket

I'm trying to set up Jenkins to pull from a bitbucket repo (on Windows Server 2008). I've generated a key, uploaded it to bitbucket, configured Mercurial to use Plink, am running Pageant, and can clone from the command line.

When I set up the Jenkins job, it tries to clone the repo but just hangs with the "working" icon in the console output

```
Building in workspace <workspace>
$ hg clone --rev default --noupdate ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/repo <workspace>
<spinning working icon>
```

If I clone the repo from the command line, I get

```
Building in workspace <workspace>
[src] $ hg showconfig paths.default
[src] $ hg pull --rev default
<spinning working icon>
```

and it also just hangs. I've left it running overnight, no error message, nothing.

I can put use `https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/repo` and it checks out fine from Jenkins.

Comment: Is Jenkins running with the same account than the one able to clone from the command line? Does Jenkins session knows what `%HOME%` is? (because ssh info will be searched in `%HOME%/.ssh`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Jenkins running in a 32 bit tomcat doesn't like 64 bit plink. I changed it to the 32 bit plink and now it checks out fine.