# Jenkins hangs when pulling from bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am trying to setup Jenkins with Bitbucket but when I try to build, Jenkins hangs here forever:

```
[project] $ hg showconfig paths.default
[project] $ hg pull --rev default
```

I have looked at this post: [Jenkins, Mercurial, Bitbucket and SSH not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058905/jenkins-mercurial-bitbucket-and-ssh-not-working) and the documentation here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin but I still have the same issue.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and TortoiseHG 64-bit. I changed jenkins.xml to use the 64-bit jvm and still nothing. I have tried using the 32-bit Plink and still nothing.

I have also tried turning off source control from the build configuration and I am running hg pull from a batch script. I get the same thing there as well. If I run the batch in the command prompt it works...

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the console output?

Might be a credentials issue. I had a similar issue with a git repository.

Comment: I have this is where I copy-pasted this from: [project] $ hg showconfig paths.default
[project] $ hg pull --rev default

Comment: What happens when you execute that command from the console on jenkins machine?

Comment: When I run the command from the console everything works fine. I only have the problem when I run it from the Jenkins web interface. I found that it all works if I run Jenkins through Tomcat. If I run it using the Jenkins Windows service it fails.

Comment: Check which user its running under

Comment: I'm running it with security turned off. If security is on should I create a Jenkins user with the same username as the Windows user?

Comment: Try to do the checkout via console under the same user as jenkins